# Executable not working when .pyc files are in same directory

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7, pyinstaller

Could someone explain why or how to fix this.

I create an executable using pyinstaller and it works fine. When the scripts .pyc files are present in the same directory and the executable, the executable quits with an error(bellow). And if i remove the *.pyc files the executable works just fine.

```
Y:\BatchPlot\New folder>"Batch Plot.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller\iu.py", line 436, in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller\iu.py", line 521, in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "Y:\BatchPlot\View.py", line 10, in <module>
    from Tkinter import *
ImportError: from-import-* object has no __dict__ and no __all__
```

Comment: Its a shared folder and some user can execute the script directly while people without python interpreter can execute the executable. Plus i don't understand why it does that and would love to understand what is going on here.